# Timestamp in Tomcat logs is wrong

Tags: tomcat, log-files, timezone

For some reason, the timestamp in my Tomcat logs is off. The system clock is correct, and set to PST, but the Tomcat logs appear to be using GMT. I haven't been able to find this setting anywhere...hoping someone can shed some light.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Tomcat?

Comment: It's version 6.0.20

Answer (score 4):

The `JVM` might have the wrong timezone set as a default.

Add a `JVM` option `-Duser.timezone=US/Pacific` (use the `JAVA_OPTS` property)

(also do a `ps | grep java` to look at the `JVM` command line and see if this option is already set for `UTC`, perhaps by a configuration setting or environment variable).

Answer (score 1):

Most logging systems default to UTC. This keeps them readable across timezones.
It also allows you to mix logs from different timezones where applicable.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, although having Apache and Tomcat logging with different timezones, and the application correcting to yet another timezone makes troubleshooting a pain.

Comment: @Thody, I agree with that. Which is why everything should be in UTC and can be externally converted if necessary. Things get into trouble once timezones are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Has the timezone of the system changed since Tomcat was started?  I've had problems where Tomcat picks up the timezone when it first starts, and then refuses to accept a new reality until you kill it and start again.

Comment: Nope, the system time has remained the same. I've actually restarted Tomcat several times as well.

Answer (score 0):

Java has its own implementation of the `tzdata`.
For instance, in my ubuntu servers, java's timezone definitions are in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.14/jre/lib/zi`
While the system one are under `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`

You can specify which timezone java should use by passing the option `-Duser.timezone=$TZ`
where `$TZ` is the relative path to the timezone file under `zi`
for example: `-Duser.timezone=Etc/GMT+3`

Comment: It's better to use the named time zone rather than GMT+3.  This allow for proper handling daylight savings time.   In other words, use US/Pacific instead of GMT-8.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Java uses the value in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` as the timezone value when starting up.  On my system that was:

```
ZONE="America/New_York"
```

Change that value to what you want and restart tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem due to  `-Duser.timezone=UTC`
You can expose this out with `ps -edf | grep catalina` if using Linux